# When I turn on the computer, network is disconnected. When disabled and enabled it works

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have one onboard network card... when I switch on the computer, sometimes its disconnected... if I disable and enable the network from network sharing center, it works. Why is this happening?

[image: (I have also attached an image of the network and sharing center)]

Comment: Have you tried updating the drivers?

Comment: @r.tanner.f Nope :) I'll try it. What else can i do?

Comment: Start with driver updates.  Next is a possible firmware update.  Windows updates all good?  When did this start happening?  Any pattern to this?  Random occurrence?

Comment: Clarify the screen shot maybe. I'm seeing "No Internet access" versus "Disconnected...

Comment: @r.tanner.f Yes.. no internet!

Comment: which adapter are you using?  try disabling the "task offload" in "properties" > "advanced" for your device in "device manager"